Ask about chrome extensions. How to block file downloads
// background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  blockDownloads,
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"] },
  ["blocking"]
);

function blockDownloads(details) {
  
  if (isDownloadRequest(details)) {
    
    return { cancel: true };
  }
}

// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Block Downloads",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Block all downloads on web pages",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}

Error content
Unchecked runtime.lastError: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners. Be sure to declare the webRequestBlocking permission in your manifest.
Please help me correct them
I tried to edit them to look like this
{
  "name": "Download Blocker",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "Blocks file downloads (declarative approach)",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "webRequest" // Needed for observing requests
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "declarativeNetRequest": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "id": "blockDownloads",
        "priority": 1,
        "condition": {
          "url": {
            "pathSuffix": ".pdf" // Assuming you want to block PDFs
          },
          "types": ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xhr", "ping", "other"] // Block all request types
        },
        "action": {
          "type": "cancel"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

however there was an error
Unrecognized manifest key 'declarativeNetRequest'.
Please help me correct them


In manifest.json it's declarative_net_request, not declarativeNetRequest. 2) There's no need for webRequest at all, remove it and remove the background script.

